# Genre of ominous music used for anime cutscenes when the villain approaches

Tags: identify-this-genre, instrumental

(Migrated from anime and manga upon advice)

The following piece of music is extracted from some video on the internet (which the twitter link cannot be included here due to the content is rather violent): https://soundcloud.com/user-873168135/unknown-anime-crisis-type-music-extracted-from-another-website

It sounds very familiar and seemed to be something from anime, and I am trying to at least identify the genre of such music. I am not sure if it is actually an original composition used by that author, or a fragment taken from some known music, as such is common in most short videos of length around 2 mins.

**Detailed search attempts**

1. Known information

The source video where the music is found is posted in 19 April, thus if it is not an original production, then it has to exist somewhere. As it is extracted from a video, there is no known album cover.

The music has no lyrics and seemed to be orchestra based and consists of the following instruments: At least 3 three types of smooth bass, some kind of war drums, some kind of African drum, a violin superimposed with a female choir, some kind of gong like wind crashing instrument.

Similar music of that nature (especially that haunting female choir) tend to appear in cutscenes in anime when a towering or apocalyptic villain and evil is descending towards the world or the casts, or when some kind of emergency situation happens.

2. Impressions and youtube, google searches

Keywords that I can think of that describe this genre (if a genre exists for it): Anime, Crisis, Invasion, Intense, Urgent, Dark, Fast-paced, Emergency, Towering, Disaster, Villain, Evil, Witch, Rush

General: Regardless of which keyword (or combinations thereof), the first 6 pages of youtube results is flooded by those long compilation videos mainly produced by the suit of accounts known as epicmusicworld, trailermusicworld, theprimecronus etc. which contains cliche epic cinematic music that does not match the impression of this music piece. All evil keywords (except for one combination below) return mostly dark fantasy genre music, which is too peaceful and slow to be similar to the music in question.

To prevent the post from getting too long, some of the more promising keywords include:

Anime villain: [Fairy Tail 2014 OST 2 - 31 - Mard Geer Tartaros The Underworld King](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8QkxhfbljFc) reproduced the forebrooding feeling of the music, but it is not it since it is too masculine and organ heavy. [Fairy Tail - Goddess of the Slave Planet Kyouka](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wwe0BoQx_ZU) reproduced the evil witch feeling of the choir, but is too slow paced and organ heavy instead of string heavy to be a match

(technically Rush, but that keyword will not return the music to be mentioned, thus this search is based on memory): [The Limit from Steins:Gate](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c1_GXJeE0j8) reproduces the urgency and tension, but is not intense enough to capture the vibe of the music.

3. Shazam, SoundHound, AudioTag, ACRCloud

They return no matches, regardless of how many times and which section of the music I choose to play to them. That suggests it is an ACG or video game music since these services tend to have a deficit of them in their databases.

Comment: Is the video which the music comes from the original ?  or is the music added to a similar video ? wondering if the video can give clues to the particular story it comes from, which might then lead to more info about the music....

Comment: That video is the only source I can find for that music so far, and the video is an original 3D animation created by that Japanese twitter user. The story is basically an explorer get caught in a dungeon trap and trying to break free, and that music plays throughout the video. In my opinion, for that kind of story, that is a wrong choice of music to describe such scenario. I cannot really deduce whether the music is also original as the volume fade seemed to suggest it is part of something larger, for I do heard similar things before when watching anime 10 years ago

Comment: though to be honest, it is the genre that interested me more, because I want to find similar musics to listen to, and that is where the roadblock is as the searches kept giving me irrelevant stuff regardless of filters

Answer (score 2):

I think your best bet for characterizing this genre is as "industrial," possibly with the modifiers "soundtrack", "epic," "orchestral", "hybrid" or "steampunk," depending on which tweak brings you closest to what you want.

> Industrial music is a genre of experimental music which draws on harsh, transgressive or provocative sounds and themes. AllMusic defines industrial music as the "most abrasive and aggressive fusion of rock and electronic music" that was "initially a blend of avant-garde electronics experiments (tape music, musique concrète, white noise, synthesizers, sequencers, etc.) and punk provocation".
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Industrial_music

See if these tracks fit what you are looking for:

- [Mekanika](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mtNDm8DuFzE)
- [Industrial Megamix](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c0WActw9OpI&t=51s)
- [The Matrix Reloaded soundtrack](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nTiCGbNcwb8)
- [Epic Modern and Aggressive Hybrid-Orchestral Mix](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TKxWOThMZLU)
- [Industrial / Steampunk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P29hggUXm_s)

Comment: Thanks for trying, but:
All 5 of them lack that building up choir and drum/percussion in the sound sample that gives that towering evil impression

Mekanika: That's definitely industrial, but I don't get a darkness or evil vibe from it
Industrial Megamix: That's even more industrial, but it lack that tension buildup of the sound sample
Matrix reloaded soundtracks are too classical, too slow and too on the mystery side
Epic modern (whatever) is precisely that cliche epic cinematic music that I do not want
That particular industrial steampunk has a haunting choir, but

Comment: its intensity and hence the towering evil impression is overshadowed by the industrial sounds which make it sounds like a mix of technology and cyberspace, whereas the sound sample is in a way more magical or non technological sounding. Checking for other steampunk music also found no matching impression, probably because steampunk is "too metallic"

Comment: In conclusion, it is probably not steampunk nor industrial

Answer (score 1):

*As per the OP [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/50241758#50241758):*

This music is best described as "confrontation music."  It's music used on soundtracks for scenes where the heroes and villains are confronting each other, so it has an ominous, epic feel to it:

EXAMPLE: [Detroit: Become Human OST - Confrontation Scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5MyUq9hsL6w)